# How to foreach object in the array on nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

`

```
const data = [{'name': 'Apip'}, {'name': 'Rohmat'}, {'name': 'ujang'}]
data.forEach(function (response) {
     res.json(response)
})
```

`

I did the code above it doesn't work and then it throws an error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Comment: Can you share what output you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the data in a batch:

```js
const data = [{'name': 'Apip'}, {'name': 'Rohmat'}, {'name': 'ujang'}]
res.json(response)
```

See [Why can't I use res.json() twice in one post request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50668533/why-cant-i-use-res-json-twice-in-one-post-request)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just response the same array object, then you should write res.json(data).

```
const data = [{'name': 'Apip'}, {'name': 'Rohmat'}, {'name': 'ujang'}]
res.json(data)
```

But, if you are doing some check or modification within forEach to array object then it depend how you want the output.

```
const data = [{'name': 'Apip'}, {'name': 'Rohmat'}, {'name': 'ujang'}]
var modified_data = []
data.forEach(function (response) {
    // DO SOME CHECK OR CHANGE IN THE ARRAY OBJECT 
    // modified_data.push(// Your modified data) 
})
res.json(modified_data);
```

You are getting this error is because, you have already sent result in the body, and forEach is trying to set the header again.